# Is Stack Exchange immune to DDoS and DoS attacks?

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service, stack-overflow

I have heard that DDoS and DoS attacks work most of the time and that they are used when SQL insertion and other methods fail. I know Stack Exchange has a lot of programmers, and that they have this stack which deals with such things. What I want to know is if Stack Exchange is immune to DDoS attacks. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is immune to DDoS attacks, no resource is infinite. It may take a bit more effort, but any service can be taken down if you have enough resources. Upstream connections can be saturated, webservers can be overloaded with requests, etc. So the same goes for Stack Exchange.

Stack Exchange staff actually wrote an a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/16/stack-under-attack-what-we-learned-about-handling-ddos-attacks/) on how they deal with DDoS attacks and lessons learned.

Answer (score 1):

Stackexchange may not be immune, but it has very good prevention methods. It has a rate limiter which prevents a certain amount of requests from coming through in a certain time frame. In addition, it will automatically block accounts and ip addresses if they are malicious.

Comment: I would call "detonate high explosives inside a datacenter" anything but simple...